# Looking for that cool astronomical and spaceflight simulation website that's been discussed here

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There were several questions here about n-body simulations and spacecraft trajectories that were asked in relation to the development of a cool astronomical and spaceflight simulation website.

The site had a dozen or two pre-defined simulations and a numerical integration engine with various user-adjustable settings. It was pretty impressive!

I can't remember the website, the user, nor find any of the questions, and I want to track down the calculation so I can link to it in a comment on [another cool astronomical simulation-related SE post](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43314/7982)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's [flightclub.io](https://flightclub.io)?

Comment: Yep there is that, but that one is primarily spaceflight but the one I'm thinking of had mostly (but not completely) natural, astronomical bodies i.e. planets, asteroids. The user has asked several questions about simulation (math, code) and the name of the software was something reminiscent of the beautify of heavenly motion (sorry, adjectives fail me).

Comment: Celestia? https://celestia.space

Comment: It's one SE user who wrote it by themselves for fun. It's a website, you choose a simulation and then it starts grinding away numerically integrating using your browser and making your computer overheat (at least mine). It's got a github page also.

Comment: Ah, I've just run across one of the author's posts https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38515/12102 **update:** and another one of their posts lead me to it! https://gravitysimulator.org/